# SML - Find occurences in lists to form ordered pairs

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I'm trying to write a function in SML that takes in a list of ints and will output a list of ordered pairs of ints.  The ordered pairs first int is the int that occurred in the input list and the second int in the ordered pair is the number of times it occurred in the input list.  Also the list returned should be in ascending order according to the first int in the ordered pairs.

For example input list `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5]` would output as `[(1,3), (2, 1), (3, 2), (5, 1)]`.

So far I have a function that uses `foldl`

---

**UPDATED** the code since original post.

```
fun turnIntoPairs l = foldl (fn (e, a) => if List.exists (fn (x, _) => x = e) a then x + 1 else a @ [(e, 1)]) [] l;
```

I'm having trouble updating the list where I find the ordered pair that is already in the list - I want to add one to the second int in the ordered pair that was found while it's still in the list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SMLNJ\\bin\.run\run.x86-win32.exe: Fatal error -- Uncaught exception Error with 0
raised at ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27

[autoloading done]
C:\Users\Localadmin\Desktop\CS 671\Program 3\commonFactors.sml:1.87 Error: unbound variable or constructor: x
C:\Users\Localadmin\Desktop\CS 671\Program 3\commonFactors.sml:1.44-1.110 Error: types of if branches do not agree [literal]
then branch: int
else branch: (''Z * int) list
in expression:
    if (List.exists (fn <pat> => <exp>)) a
    then <errorvar> + 1
    else a @ (e,1) :: nil
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Look at your error. It's complaining that `find` and `x` don't exist. By `find` I think you mean `List.find`, although the type signature for that one doesn't fit with the arguments you're trying to give it.

Comment: Also, the same question is being answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372083/turn-a-list-with-common-items-in-to-a-list-of-ordered-pairs)

Comment: I saw that post, I was writing this question when that one was posted.  I used that information to start writing this function that I'm now having trouble with.

Comment: So I got rid of exists because it wasn't what I was trying to do.  I was trying to see if there was a pair of (e, _) in the list.  I updated my current function in the question post.  Does the `if List.exists (fn (x, _) => x = e) a then ....` part look correct for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure how to fix your current program, but you can solve this problem by splitting it in two: grouping equal elements and then ordering the list.

```
(* Groups successive equal elements into a tuples (value, count) *)
fun group (l as (x :: _)) = 
    let val (firstGroup, rest) = List.partition (fn y => x = y) l
    in 
        (x, List.length firstGroup) :: (group rest)
    end
  | group [] = []

(* Now that we have our elements grouped, what's left is to order
   them as required. *)
fun turnIntoPairs xs =
    ListMergeSort.sort (fn ((x, _), (y, _)) => x >= y) (group xs)
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternate solution.  Ideally I want to fix my own code so I can better understand how foldl works and so I'm not just copying someone elses.  Great solution though!

Answer (score 1):

Let's just look at the function you're passing to `foldl`:

```
(fn (e, a) => if List.exists (fn (x, _) => x = e) a then x + 1 else a @ [(e, 1)])
```

The first problem (which the type-checker is complaining about) is that your `if` expression returns either `x + 1`, or `a @ [(e, 1)]`, which seems problematic on account of the former being a value of type `int` and the latter being of type `(int * int) list`.

Let's rewrite your code using some helper functions that I won't define and see if it gets clearer:

```
(fn (e, a) => if List.exists (fn (x, _) => x = e) a then increment a e else a @ [(e, 1)])
```

Where `increment` has the type `(int * int) list -> int -> (int * int) list`.

Can you implement `increment`?

Comment: I don't think I can implement that method because I'm getting errors about x being unknown when trying to call increment a x?

Comment: Sorry, was meant to be `e`, not `x`.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gian, I would prefer to divide this into two functions: One that folds and one helper function that inserts. Incidentally, the insert function would take an element and an existing `(int * int) list` just as the accumulator function that fold accepts these two arguments.

Normally I would write an insert function curried (i.e. `insert x xs`) but if I write it uncurried (i.e. `insert (x, xs)`), I can pass it directly to `foldl`:

```
fun insert (x, [])          = [(x,1)]
  | insert (x, ((y,c)::xs)) =
    if x = y then (y,c+1)::xs else (y,c)::insert (x, xs)

fun turnIntoPairs xs = foldl insert [] xs
```